# MUI + React Hook Form: Fill out TextField value but then can't modify the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using the combination of MUI + React Hook Form, so I've created a `CustomTextField.tsx` component to make it worked.

```js
// CustomTextField.tsx
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

export default function CustomTextField(props: any) {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={props.name}
      control={props.control}
      render={({
        field: { onChange, value },
        fieldState: { error },
        formState
      }) => <TextField onChange={onChange} {...props} />}
    />
  );
}
```

Then at the app/parent level, I want to these steps:

1. Fetch data and display to the TextField.
2. Modify the text in TextField
3. Submit the new value in TextField

This is my approach:

```js
//App.tsx
export default function App() {
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState<string>("");
  ...
  return (
...
        <CustomTextField
          control={control}
          name="description"
          label="Description"
          type="text"
          variant="outlined"
          value={fetchedData ? fetchedData: ""}     //<-- fetched data is set to value of TextField to display
        />
...
  );
}
```

With this approach, I managed to display the `fetchedData` on TextField UI, but can not modify that data on text field. Also when I submit, the data is not correct to what display on the TextField

I have created a codesandbox link for this: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-sanne-x858dx?file=/src/App.tsx:190-1155

How can I display the fetchedData, but also can modify the data in text field and then submit through React Hook Form later?

Comment: I don't see an onChange event for your implementation, you need the onChange event to change the state so that it can be updated.

Comment: I have to pass the onChange from Controller to TextField instead, so the React Hook Form works. I don't know how I can use onChange both parent level, and component level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [@Linda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431574/linda-paiste) solution, I've came up with this approach, that ensures the functionality working with the style of MUI TextField as well.

The `setValue` will be passed down to custom TextField to set the value. And to keep the `{...props}` functionality, I delete the `setValue` props before spreading it on MUI TextField.

```js
//CustomTextField.tsx
import { TextField } from "@mui/material"
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form"

export default function CustomTextField(props: any) {
  const propsObj = { ...props }
  delete propsObj.setValue
  return (
    <Controller
      name={props.name}
      control={props.control}
      defaultValue={""}
      render={({
        field: { onChange, value },
        fieldState: { error },
        formState,
      }) => (
        <TextField
          value={value}
          onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
            onChange(value)
            if (props?.setValue) props.setValue(props.name, value)
          }}
          {...propsObj}
        />
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

```js
//App.tsx
export default function App(){
  const { control, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm()
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(...)}>
      <CustomTextField
        control={control}
        name="description"
        label="Description"
        type="text"
        variant="outlined"
        setValue={setValue}
      />
    <form/>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to is have a text input where the user can type a value, but you can also set the value externally by clicking the "Fetch Data" button.

Your setup includes conflicting sources of truth.  The `value` of the field is set to the `data` state and the value which is stored in the `react-hook-form` state is ignored.

What you want to do is to modify the internal state of the `react-hook-form` when the button is pressed.

You can delete the local state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<string>("");
```

Instead, you can use the `setValue` helper function from the form:

```
const { control, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm<FormValues>();

const fetchingData = () => {
  setValue("description", "fetched description Text");
};
```

In your `CustomTextField`, make sure that you set the `value` of the input to the `value` from the form state.

```
render={({
  field: { onChange, value },
  fieldState: { error },
  formState
}) => <CusTextField onChange={onChange} value={value} {...props} />}
```

[Complete Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-external-updates-ck4omz)

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work functionally, however, it seems like the TextField doesn't get :active, so the label overlapped the value text. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Interesting.  There might be something in the react-hook form package that can handle the focus but I'm not super familiar with the package.  You can pass a `ref` down to the DOM `<input>` element and call `inputRef.current?.focus()` inside `fetchingData()`.

Comment: I think that setting a default value like "" (empty string) do the trick. This is something a don't like of MUI (I'm new with MUI btw)